# C++ create a square floor plane using ray tracing. SegFault

Tags: c++, raytracing, plane

I have been attempting to implement a plane using ray tracing and phong.  I haven't been able to get it to show up yet.

I currently have 3 spheres with shadows working, but can't seem to get the plane to work.  Can anyone spot an issue with why my plane isn't showing and why the segFault is happening? (I explain the exact line and how I can AVOID getting a segFault below, so I feel I have pinpointed the issue)

I would like the plane to be like a floor where I can see the shadows.  I've included only the relevant plane code and omitted the sphere stuff for readability.  If someone requests it I can include it.  (Sphere stuff working: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbIPI.jpg , line "tmin=t" of the squarePlane code commented out to show this.)

The SegFault happens in the implementPhong function on

```
vec3 R = vec3 (0,0,0);
//normalize(reflect(-L, N));
//vec3 (0,0,0);
```

If I use the commented out normalize function instead of my temporary `vec3(0,0,0)`.

It will also segFault if I move my

```
squarePlane.normal = normalize(vec3(0,0.5,3)); // to (vec3(0,1,0))
```

---

```
//********** Global Variables *********
RgbImage * myImage;
vec3 nEye(0.0,0.0,-5.0);
vec3 lightSource1(-2.0,-1.5,0.0);
vec3 lightSource2(0.0,-2.0,0.0);
float tmin=100.0;


struct Ray
{
    vec3 pt;
    vec3 vecDir;
};

struct Prim
{
    vec3 origin;
    double radius;
    double underSquare;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse_albedo;
    vec3 specular_albedo;
    float specular_power;
    vec3 light_intensity;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 pt1;
    vec3 pt2;
    vec3 pt3;
};


vec3 trace(Ray ray){
    Prim squarePlane;
    Prim pickSphere;
    tmin = 100;
    vec3 pixelColor(0,0,1);
    squarePlane.pt1 = vec3(-0.2,0.0,0.0);
    squarePlane.pt2 = vec3(0.2,0.0,0.0);
    squarePlane.pt3 = vec3(-0.2,0.1,0.0);
    squarePlane.ambient=vec3(0.329412, 0.223529, 0.027451);
    squarePlane.diffuse_albedo=vec3(0.780392, 0.568627, 0.113725);
    squarePlane.specular_albedo = vec3(0.992157,0.941176,0.807843);
    squarePlane.specular_power = 27.8974;
    squarePlane.light_intensity = vec3(1,1,1);
    squarePlane.normal = normalize(vec3(0,1,0));

    float D = 0;
    float denom = dot(squarePlane.normal, nVecDir);
    float numer = dot(squarePlane.normal, nEye) + D;
    vec3 hitTemp;
    vec3 hitPoint;
    if (denom!=0){
        float t= -(dot(squarePlane.normal, nEye) + D) / denom;
        if (t>=0){
            tmin=t;
        }
    }
    //pickSphere = squarePlane;

    pickSphere = checkForIntersection(nEye, nVecDir, spheres, false);  // last parameter is for print debugging

    if (tmin != 100){ //if tmin has changed, we found and intersection, send shadow ray
        vec3 hitTemp(nVecDir.x*tmin, nVecDir.y*tmin, nVecDir.z*tmin);
        vec3 hitPoint = (nEye + hitTemp);
        shadowRay.vecDir = (normalize(lightSource1 - (hitPoint)));

        tmin = 100;  // Set tmin for a new ray trace.
        checkForIntersection(hitPoint, shadowRay.vecDir, spheres, true);

        if (tmin != 100){ //if tmin does not equal 100, we found an intersection, this point is in shadow, return ambient.
            pixelColor = pickSphere.ambient;
            return pixelColor;
        }
        else {
            pickSphere.normal = hitPoint - pickSphere.origin;
            pixelColor = implementPhong(pickSphere,nEye,hitPoint);
            //pixelColor = vec3(0,1,0);
            return pixelColor;
        }
    }
    else{
        return pixelColor;
    }
}


vec3 implementPhong(Prim drawSphere, vec3 camera, vec3 hitPoint){ 
    vec3 L = drawSphere.light_intensity * normalize(lightSource1 - hitPoint);
    vec3 N = normalize(drawSphere.normal);
    vec3 V = normalize(camera - hitPoint);
    vec3 R = vec3 (0,0,0); //normalize(reflect(-L, N)); //vec3 (0,0,0);
    float zero = 0;

    vec3 diffuse = std::max<float>(dot(N, L), zero) * drawSphere.diffuse_albedo;

    vec3 specular = pow(std::max<float>(dot(R, V), zero), drawSphere.specular_power) * drawSphere.specular_albedo; 

    vec3 color = drawSphere.ambient + diffuse + specular;

    return color;
}
```

Comment: Try running your code under valgrind - you may have corrupted your heap at some earlier point in the program.

Comment: Not sure I'll be able to... School computers.  Working remotely via cygwin currently.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Why are you assigning `squarePlane` to `pickSphere` only to immediately re-assign to `pickSphere`? Do you have any funky aliasing going on?

Comment: There are a couple of things missing to answer this question: What type is pickSphere? (is it a global variable?). What type is nEye? What does the copy-constructor of Prim look like? BTW: Are you sure you want to pass drawSphere by value and not by const reference? And did you realize that you declare hitTemp and hitPoint twice?

Comment: pickSphere is type Prim. nEye is vec3. drawSphere is pickSphere.  I've updated my question with this information and gotten rid of the first picksphere.

Comment: Now that I've added this information, does this get taken "off hold"

Comment: @molbdnilo No funky aliasing.  This is my current image: http://imgur.com/i936UID .  I pretty much do the exact same thing as what I'm doing with my Prim squarePlane, but of course calculate for a sphere instead of a plane, and have 3 of them.  No segFaults.